# No-SQL Database for large values

Tags: database, nosql

I am searching for a key value store that can handle values with a size of some Gigabytes. I have had a look on [Riak](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak), [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/), [CouchDb](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

I want to store a workspace of a user (equals to a directory in filesystem, recursively with subdirectories and files in it) in this DB. Of course I could use the file system but then I dont't have features such as caching in RAM, failover solution, backup and replication/clustering that are supported by Redis for instance.

This implies that most of the values saved will be binary data, eventually some Gigabytes big, as one file in a workspace is mapped to one key-value tupel.

Has anyone some experiences with any of these products?

Comment: What are the multi-gigabyte values? Binary data? Massive strings of text?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: Still not picturing exactly what the data is. Can't you break it up into smaller chunks? And why are you saying "no-sql"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are now using MongoDB, as it supports large binary values, is very popular and has a large user base. Maybe we are going to switch to another store, but currently it looks very good!

Answer (score 2):

First off, getting an MD5 or CRC32 from data size of GB is going to be painfully expensive computationally. Probably better to avoid that. How about store the data in a file, and index the filename?

If you insist, though, my suggestion is still to just store the hash, not the entire data value, with a lookup array/table to the final data location. Safeness of this approach (non-unique possibility) will vary directly with the number of large samples. The longer the hash you create -- 32bit vs 64bit vs 1024bit, etc -- the safer it gets, too. Most any dictionary system in a programming language, or a database engine, will have a binary data storage mechanism. Failing that, you could store a string of the Hex value corresponding to the hashed number in a char column.

Comment: Why do I need to compute hashes of Gigabytes? My keys are very short strings.

Comment: OP: "values with a size of some Gigabytes" - but, with this comment I now see you may mean a set of values which will in total occupy a lot of RAM. and, that makes sense, too.

Comment: I disagree; hashing a long array of bytes simply takes a long time - this does not make it non-trivial. Nontrivial problems either involve very complex algorithms, or tend to have a high time complexity. Hashing data is pretty much O(n), i.e. linear time hence not really a big deal even for very large files.

Comment: But will I really need to create hashes of that size? At what point? I dont understand it, as my keys are very short and I think only the keys not the data=value will be hashed.

Comment: @Heinrich - can you edit the post with more information about what you're actually doing? our discussion is apparently not on target, but it's more due to a lack of information than of expertise (as in, not mine, but the SO members as a whole). If your keys are short, what is the data you're indexing with those keys?

Comment: Sorry for that, I added some comments on the purpose of the usage.